# Catch all Wordpress exceptions?

Tags: wordpress, exception

it is possible to create a global exception handler for Wordpress so that I log all exceptions in a file or db so that I can analyze them later on ?

PS I am a WP noob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found

```
class WP_Error
```

in classes.php so I guess I can tinker there